# ASP.NET MVC UnauthorizedResult adding unwanted parameters to login url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this problem in a production application where query string parameters are being added to the login redirect url. To reproduce this, create a new MVC project (I tested with both MVC2 and MVC3 R2). In the `HomeController` add the following action:

```
public ActionResult Break()
{
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```

Launch the application and hit `/home/break?a=1&b=2`. So this should naturally redirect to `/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/home/break%3fa%3d1%26b%3d2` but it actually adds the requested parameters (`&a=1&b=2`) to the end of the url as well:

[image]

Why is this happening? There's no need for those parameters to be added since the encoded url in `ReturnUrl` has the required parameters. I thought it would be something in the production application, but if the steps above are followed, a default MVC application will reproduce this as well. Any thoughts on how to solve this are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done so that the LogOn action will have access to the original (unencoded) querystring values.

So given the URI

`http://localhost:65183/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=/home/break%3fa%3d1%26b%3d2&a=1&b=2`

The ReturnUrl key/value pair is the URI to redirect to after a successful login and it contains the encoded querystring pairs from the previous request.

To change this behaviour you'd need to override how the redirect is being built.

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Response.RedirectLocation != null && Response.RedirectLocation.Contains("ReturnUrl"))
    {
        // change redirect URI
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense now that I think about, it just made me very curious initially. I will leave this be since it's by design.